# How do you save a custom linked list (double linked list?) on to a file?

Tags: java, load, linked-list, save

I have a linked list called CalendarLinkedList which the data members are all user defined,

```
GregorianCalendar date;
Monetary savings;
Monetary loss;
Memo memo;
Debt debt;
int counter;

CalendarLinkedList next;
CalendarLinkedList previous;
```

Monetary objects consist of a double and a String array

```
double value;
String[] type;

public Monetary()
{
    setValue(0);
    type = new String [50];
}
```

Memo consists only of String

```
String writing;

    public Memo()
    {
        writing = "";
    }
```

Debt is an extension of Monetary with one more double value and two Gregorian Calendars.

Is there anyway which I can store this on a text file?
It will be better if you guys tell me how to load it from the text file after saving also.

I know the codes are very inefficient but I wanted to at least create the link list without any help. I've been stuck here for a couple of while and finally came to this place for help.

Comment: Do you really need text files, or can it be a binary one?

Comment: Text files are necessary

Comment: You need to give each element a unique ID, because there is not a good way to serialize the Java references.  That way the next item reference can be to the next item's id.  Beyond that, use XML?

Comment: Whack it into a CSV file.

Comment: You mean the elements in calendarLinkedList should all have a unique ID?

Comment: CSV files look interesting but can it be used without any addons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use text files, then what I would suggest is to find some sort of scheme to correspond lines to attributes and from that scheme, rebuild the linked list as you read them for file.
As the scheme, look at this small example. Imagine you only wanted to save a list of Monetary. What you could do was, for each item on the list, you would save, in each line:

1. The value of the variable 'value'
2. The length of the array of strings (let's say *n* strings)
3. *n* strings

Now, when reading the file, you would firstly create an empty Monetary item, and you would read the first line of the text file to fill 'value'. Then, you would read the value of *n* and it would indicate you how many lines you still would have to read to fill the string array. You would do this procedure till you found an EOF.

Now, what I've said applies only for the case of saving an instance of Monetary. For you linked list, you would do the same, but for more objects. Was I clear enough?